# Scroll absolute position div with page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using fancybox 2 and I would like for the fancybox modal to scroll with the page, instead of being fixed to the center and having a max-height. How can I do this?

```
$('.fancybox-open').fancybox({
     openEffect  : 'none',
     closeEffect : 'none',
     width: '100px',
     'closeBtn' : true,
     afterLoad   : function() {
        this.content.html();
     }
});
```

Comment: Can you show the code you have...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the option `autoCenter: false` when initializing your FancyBox: http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs